# How to calculate sum of a column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

When I run my WPF and pick a date, it shows the cars rented for that month. In the last column it shows the total price of the rented car. I want to be able to calculate the sum of the values in that total price column. However I'm getting an error that underlines "Cells" in my code.

```
private void sumButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < TruckDataGrid2.Items.Count; ++i)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(TruckDataGrid2.Items[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }
            sumText.Text = sum.ToString();



    }
```

I also want to show the sum in a textbox. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong.

All the packages im using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using PartB.Models;
```

Comment: What's the `ItemsSource` of `TruckDataGrid2`?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work in WPF

```
for (int i = 0; i < TruckDataGrid2.Items.Count; ++i)      
sum += (decimal.Parse((TruckDataGrid2.Columns[2].GetCellContent(dataGrid.Items[i]) as 
TextBlock).Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < TruckDataGrid2.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(TruckDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
}
sumText.text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: I have also tried that solution however, Rows[i] can't be used on datagridview so I had to use items[i]. Is there any other way? @Sanjay Singh Chouhan

Comment: I had a look however, i still cant select "Rows". The only options I had was "RowStyle","CanUserAddRows" etc @Sanjay Singh Chouhan

Comment: check this link it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48059974/9822301

Comment: Don't just throw code and/or links as a way of giving an answer, try to explain the problem to the OP. Also, if you think the question is a duplicate, flag it as so and just add a comment to the question, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value of the column from the corresponding property of your data object. For example, if you have set or bound the `ItemsSource` property of your `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable<Car>` and the `Car` class has a `Price` property, this should work:

```
private void sumButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TruckDataGrid2.Items.Count; ++i)
    {
        Car car = TruckDataGrid2.Items[i] as Car; //try to cast item to your data object type
        if (car != null)
            sum += car.Price;
    }
    sumText.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```